# How to switch to another activity using imageview in reycleview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So, I am basically building an expense tracker app. I have successfully implemented Recycleview which contains Transactions' history. Now, what I am trying to achieve is to use an arrow imageview in the recycleview which will forward me to another activity when it is clicked. Any help will be appreciated on it.

Answer (score 1):

in your adapter class inside onBindViewHolder method add

```
holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherActivity.class);
            
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```